# BeautifulSoup url scraping

Tags: python, request, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying out BeautifulSoup for the first time.

I have this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/alv8dq6k35n4m2k/For+You.zip

I want to catch the direct download url from the download button which is 
http://download2110.mediafire.com/niz8p9iu6r9g/alv8dq6k35n4m2k/For+You.zip

What I have tried so far.

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.findAll('a')
```

I think the last function `findAll('a')`would find all the links from that page, but I could not find the direct download url in my `links`list.

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, how can I grab that link with beautifulsoup. I inspect the element in Chrome Developer Console and I see that the link is there.

Comment: it is generated using javascript so not visible when requests gets the html

Comment: Does that mean that it is not possible to get that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to extract the url from the javascript:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.mediafire.com/download/alv8dq6k35n4m2k/For+You.zip")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

link = soup.find("div",{"class":"download_link"})
import re

url = re.findall("http.*.zip?",link.text)[0]
```

Comment: genius! I never thought about targeting the div first and then go down from there. thanks.

Comment: Strange. Am I missing something here? I immediately followed your step and run the code and it worked fine. But after a minute or so, ```link``` list is None. Does it still work for you?

```File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    url = re.findall("http.*.zip?",link.text)[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: @Zip, yes but there is a limit on how many times you can make a request, if you go over it you will have to wait a few minutes. Do you want to save the zip?

Comment: Oh. Is it set by mediafire server? Anyway to overcome it? No, I do not want to save it. This is just a testing. But request sent from Chrome browser seems to work fine though. I got no captcha stuff.

Comment: I bet if you use your browser you will see a captcha so I don't think bar changing your ip there will be an easy way around it.

Comment: when I print url I get `http://download1719.mediafire.com/gayq0l4hbkdg/alv8dq6k35n4m2k/For+You.zip` so it is definitely working. I you don't want to save it what do you want to do with it??

Comment: It's working again. I think you are right about those limit. When I change the ip address to another one, the script works just fine.

Comment: for me I had to go to my browser and enter a captcha or wait a few minutes to access again.